# Minimal graph with confusing (?) property

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

Let $n \geq 2$ and $C = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^{2n} \mid \lvert x \rvert = \lvert y \rvert \} \subset \mathbf{R}^{2n}$ be the Simons cone. (Whether this is area-minimizing or not does not seem to play a role.)

> In short, my question is whether there can be a smooth minimal hypersurface $M$  in $\mathbf{R}^{2n} \times \mathbf{R}$ whose intersection with the plane $\{ x^{2n+1} = 0\}$ coincides exactly with $C$ in a neighborhood of the origin?

I'd always thought that this is not possible, because the intersection between the two would either be transverse, or there is a touching set of codimension two. However, by solving a suitable Dirichlet problem as described below, it seems an example can be obtained by taking $M$ to be the graph of $u$. Which of the two is right?

*Example.* Let $S_\pm$ be the two area-minimizing currents with respective boundaries $\partial S_\pm \subset \partial B^{2n}$ lying a constant, small distance of $1/100$ above and below the link of the cone. Finally, let $U \subset \mathbf{R}^{2n}$ be the domain lying between the two, inside the unit ball.

Given a small $\epsilon$, there is a unique function $u$ defined on this domain, whose graph is minimal and which has boundary values $u = \epsilon$ on the 'top' part $S_+$, $u = -\epsilon$ on the bottom, and linearly interpolating in between the two.

By symmetry, one moreover has $u(x,y) = -u(y,x)$, which implies that the function $u$ vanishes on $C$. By the maximum principle, as it has non-negative boundary values 'above' the cone, and non-positive values 'below', it must be that $\{ u = 0 \} = C \cap B^{2n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, you are mistaken about the structure of the the intersection of two minimal hypersurfaces.

In general, the intersection should be a real analytic hypersurface (in the hypersurface -- so codimension two in the ambient space) away from some lower dimensional strata that occur where the two hypersurfaces intersect non-transversely.  Moreover, at points in these "singular" strata, the intersection should (modulo some technical issues) look qualitatively like the zero set of a homogeneous  harmonic polynomial (the latter should describe the infinitesimal behavior).

The Simons' cone happens to be the zero set of the homogeneous harmonic polynomial
$$
u=|x|^2-|y|^2
$$
so it is not clear there is anything surprising about your construction.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I find this a bit confusing because I thought some version of Morse-Rado arguments should work in dimension $n$. For example, I assumed that there is an $n$-dimensional version of Rado's result: that a minimal $n$-disk $M$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ whose boundary projects homeomorphically to the boundary of a convex region in a hyperplane must be a graph. I thought the proof is via a step like "if a hyperplane $P$ intersects $\partial M$ transversally and divides it into two components, then $P$ also intersects $M$ transversally". It's confusing to me that this is false.